# Cannot display response in Dialogflow simulator. Please test on the Google Assistant simulator instead

Tags: java, android-studio, dialogflow-es, chatbot, google-assistant-sdk

I am developing an application on Android, which implements a chatbot created on dialogflow but some intents have been implemented on action on Google and when I call some intents I get this result: "Error: Cannot display response in Dialogflow simulator. Please test on the Google Assistant simulator instead"

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BotReplay {
private Activity activity;
RecyclerView chatView;
ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
EditText editMessage;
ImageButton btnSend;

//dialogFlow
private SessionsClient sessionsClient;
private SessionName sessionName;
private String uuid= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
private String TAG = "mainactivity";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chatView = findViewById(R.id.chatView);
    editMessage = findViewById(R.id.editMessage);
    btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

    chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter (messageList, this);
    chatView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
            String message = editMessage.getText().toString();
            if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                messageList.add(new Message(message, false));
                editMessage.setText("");
                sendMessageToBot(message);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    Objects.requireNonNull(chatView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    Objects.requireNonNull(chatView.getLayoutManager())
                            .scrollToPosition(messageList.size() - 1);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter text!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    setUpBot();
}


private void setUpBot(){
    try {
        InputStream stream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credential);
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream)
                .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
        String projectId = ((ServiceAccountCredentials) credentials).getProjectId();

        SessionsSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = SessionsSettings.newBuilder();
        SessionsSettings sessionsSettings = settingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(
                FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build();
        sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings);
        sessionName = SessionName.of(projectId,uuid);
        Log.d(TAG, "projectId : " + projectId);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "setUpBot : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void sendMessageToBot(String message){
    QueryInput input = QueryInput.newBuilder()
            .setText(TextInput.newBuilder().setText(message).setLanguageCode("Italian")).build();
    new SendMessageInBg(this, sessionName, sessionsClient,input).execute();
}

@Override
public void callback(DetectIntentResponse returnResponse) {
    if(returnResponse!=null) {
        String botReply = returnResponse.getQueryResult().getFulfillmentText();
        if(!botReply.isEmpty()){
            messageList.add(new Message(botReply, true));
            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                Objects.requireNonNull(chatView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(messageList.size() - 1);
            }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "failed to connect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Many of my dialogflow intents are implemented as actions on the google actions console, but I don't understand, how I can connect and use these actions on my app chat

Comment: Basically I have to create an app of this chatbot already existing, but the dialog flow intents are solved on actions console and I don't understand how they can be implemented on my app, I hope I have explained my problem more clearly

Comment: You should post the webhook code you're using, as you seem to be using a response that is not natively part of Dialogflow but only available on Actions on Google.